# Why is my InitializeComponent sub empty?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am new to vb.net programming and I am currently looking at a visual studio project at my work. To my understanding, when a new component is added to the designer of a web page, the details and properties of that component are declared within the InitializeComponent sub. I noticed that in all of the different InitializeComponent declarations throughout the project, they all have no code within them. Can anybody tell me why this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on top of solution explorer `show all files` you will be able to see files like `Form1.Designer.vb` The key here is `designer` which is a file that is automatically created for you by visual studio. Changes to it are not advised but sometimes necessary. Another good use for this file is when you would like to create `dynamic controls` which you can use code from `designer` to make it on the fly.

For asp.net this [link](http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/UnderstandingCodeBehind/UnderstandingCodeBehind.aspx) should help you get basics.

Answer (score 0):

The `InitializeComponent` sub is automatically generated when you create your project. It's generally a bad idea to modify the code in this sub manually, as it could confuse the designer.The code for this sub is intentionally hidden to prevent developers from trying to change it manually. I assure you, however, that the code is there. It is just hidden to prevent unwanted confusion.